# How to Make a makeshift add to cart system with just html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The program that I did was simple, it didn't have any database. I just improvised and placed the values of each product to the button tag. It works pretty well and all but there was a problem that I encountered. The textbox wherein you can manipulate the quantity is only working for the first quantity textbox. For example, I change the value of the second quantity textbox first e.g from initial value of "1" to "3" the result would only show that I added only 1 item. From that result, I think the problem is that the code I wrote is only reading the initial value of the other remaining quantity textboxes' (aside from the first textbox). So basically, my question is : how do I update the textbox values on key up and notify the function() that it has been updated?

My HTML :

```
    <table border = "4" cellspacing = "3" cellpadding = "3" bgcolor = "white">
    <col width = "250">
    <col width = "400">
    <col width = "200">
    <col width = "200">
    <col width = "200">

    <tr>
        <td align = "center"><h2 id = "item_name">product1</h2></td>
        <td><b>Price :</b> <span id = "item_price" value = "17.10">$17.10</span><br>
        <td><b>Quantity :</b> <input type = "text" value = "1" id = "quantity" onKeyUp="test();" style="width: 50px;"></td>
        <td align = "center"><button value="17.10" name="product" id="button1" onclick="test(this);">Add to Cart</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align = "center"><h2 id = "item_name">product2</h2></td>
        <td><b>Price :</b> <span id = "item_price" value = "39.00">$39.00</span><br>
        <td><b>Quantity :</b> <input type = "text" value = "1" id = "quantity" onKeyUp="test();" style="width: 50px;"></td>
        <td align = "center"><button value="39.00" name="product" id="button1" onclick="test(this);">Add to Cart</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align = "center"><h2 id = "item_name">product1</h2></td>
        <td><b>Price :</b> <span id = "item_price" value = "49.00">$49.00</span><br>
        <td><b>Quantity :</b> <input type = "text" value = "1" id = "quantity" onKeyUp="test();" style="width: 50px;"></td>
        <td align = "center"><button value="49.00" name="product" id="button1" onclick="test(this);">Add to Cart</button></td>
    </tr>


    </table>

<table border = "0" cellspacing = "3" cellpadding = "3" bgcolor = "white" width = "700" align = "center">   

    <tr>
    <td align = "center">Subtotal: <span id = "totaltext" value = "0">0</span>
    (<span id="items" value = "0">0</span> items)</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

My Javascript :

```
function test(button) {
    var val = parseFloat(button.getAttribute("value"));
    var quan = parseFloat(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
    var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaltext').getAttribute("value"));
    var items = parseFloat(document.getElementById('items').getAttribute("value"));

    if(button.getAttribute("name") === 'product')


    document.getElementById('totaltext').innerHTML = total + val * quan;
    document.getElementById('totaltext').setAttribute("value", total + val * quan);

    document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items + quan;
    document.getElementById('items').setAttribute("value", items + quan);


}
```

P.S here's a Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eLhsmq4p/ (Don't know why it's not working there though)

Comment: You probably do not want to do it this way, unless you want to start selling your stuff for free! Even though you do not have a database, you should still run this in PHP or another server side language.

Comment: An ID can only be used once if you want to use it properly. Since you have multiple elements with `id="quantity"`, JavaScript has no idea which one you're referring to.

Comment: This tutorial builds an add to cart system with html and JS: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-modular-javascript--net-14746

Comment: So I made a for loop (based on Colecmc's link) because of what Quantastical suggested that there's multiple id="quantity" elements. After making the for loop, I wrote something like document.getElementsById('quantity[i]').value, but it still didn't work. Also Adam, I get what you're saying. I will modify this in the near future to have a database. But right now, I just need to make it work with just the html and javascript to help me understand how it works. Once that's done, I'll apply some C# and OOP logic to it so I can link it to a database table.